# Events calendar & time

Tags: views, datetime

When working with an Event content type and creating an Events Calendar using views, is it best to keep the date and time separate or together? I was thinking of having them separately, but there is no Time field type, and if I select the content type of Date for the Time only, it messes things up, in a sense that it also requires a date, which conflicts with my Date Field. :S

The reason why I want to separate the Date from Time is because I only want the time to displayed in the calendar view.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to admin/configuration/regional and language/date and time/formats. you can add a formats. so, you click on the Type and add a type.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7?

Use admin/config/regional/date-time/formats and create a new Date/Time format that only outputs the time. Then in your view set the field display to use that format by selecting  "date and time" under "formatter." Now select your newly created format under "choose how users view dates and times."

I think that is the same in D6 as well or at least similar.

Comment: make sure to flush your cache to see any new date formats in views.

Comment: Thanks for that. However I can't see a time only date format in admin/config/regional/date-time/types/add when I try to create a new date format :( @Shane

Comment: Oh, I may have figured it out. I first created a format and then the date type. Howver, the date is now not being displayed in my view... Well, it's displaying in the PREVIEW but not the page...